# Python MySQL connector, "wrong number of arg.."

Tags: python, mysql

Can someone help and give me a tip here? I'm using Python 2.7 and MySQL-connector 1.0.12.

The following job_insert, with %f, raises the error "mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Wrong number of arguments during string formatting".

```
job = {'customer': u'Acme', 'period': 3.0, 'cost': 987654.543210123}
job_insert = "INSERT INTO f.job (customer, period, cost) VALUES (%(customer)s, %(period)f, %(cost)f);"

cursor.execute(job_insert, job)
```

When I use %s instead, mysql.connector inserts the values. However, the floats are trimmed by several decimal places, e.g. 3.0 to 3 and 987654.543210123 to 987654.5.  Both database columns are float.

```
job_insert = "INSERT INTO f.job (customer, period, cost) VALUES (%(customer)s, %(period)s, %(cost)s);"
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend using [string format](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting).

I am not quite sure of the column data type in your mysql table, usually if it is a varchcar type I put single quotes around them and numbers without single quote.

```
job_insert = "INSERT INTO f.job (customer, period, cost) VALUES ('{0}', {1}, {2});".format(job['customer'], job['period'], job['cost'])
cursor.execute(job_insert)
cursor.execute('commit')
```

This would assume your customer column is varchar and period and cost are numeric (int, float..?)

Comment: DONT do that in case your input is in any way from a front end! There is no security againts SQL Injection this way!

Answer (score 0):

So string formatting in Python is very similar to C and C like languages.

for example:

say you wanted to do

`x = "Hello buddy"` and you wanted the `buddy` to be whatever you wanted, then you would do:

`x = "Hello %s" % ("Buddy")` There are a few different types of % formats, like `%i` is for integers, `%f` is for floats, so on and so forth.

There is a newer, I think more pythonic, way to format strings, and thats with the `.format` method which you can take a look at here, http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting

Hope this helps you, admittedly I didn't fully understand your question.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited. Hopefully that makes it a little more clear?  Notice that %(period)f, %(cost)f raises the error. However, %(period)s, %(cost)s does not. But, the float is trimmed by several decimal places.